# Host telling me to cancel my booking in exchange for a discount?

Tags: hotels, booking.com, payment, pre-pay

I booked through booking.com about 2 months ago, made a prepayment and everything. The place I booked has free cancellation up until 2 weeks prior.

Now, the host has e-mailed me offering me a discount on the payment if I cancel the booking? The host says that the booking will still be mine and it will still be reserved for me, they just want me to cancel it. The host also states that it is not mandatory, it’s just an offer.

Of course, this sounds so dodgy. I’ve already made a prepayment, so there’s no way I’m going to cancel it and trust the host?

Why is the host offering me this? It’s so strange.

Comment: Following this with interest I have never heard anything like it in 30 years of traveling, maybe the host want to avoid paying the fee to booking.com ?

Comment: You’re also risking that they don’t hold the booking for you but offer it to someone willing to pay more. Generally, where financial matters are concerned, if it sounds too good to be true it usually is.

Comment: @MattDouhan trying to bypass your employer by taking cash directly from the customer without a contract and receipt is quite commonplace in certain cultures. Cheating on booking.com in the same way is a logical step.

Comment: I think you should report them and cancel your reservation trough booking i'm sure you can find a trusty host. Think this way if you do what the host is asking you'll end up in his hands he can give you a bad room or something you have no way to contest through booking, on the other hand if you refuse and go on with the reservation on booking you are starting your trip with someone dodgy to whom you already denied something. I rather start fresh new with another host from that put me in that position.

Comment: I had a similar experience with a Airbnb-type reservation through Booking.com - we were supposed to pay the host on arrival (unless I was mistaken) and he asked for a cash payment. A few days later I got an email from Booking.com to confirm a "no-show". In other words, the host keeps the cash and tells Booking.com that you never arrived. It is an easy way to keep the commission, but can land up with the host being blacklisted. For the record, the Booking.com confirmation just asked the question "Did you stay? - Yes/No" and then they said they would resolve it with the host.

Comment: @Teker It doesn't really matter if you can't contest through booking, in my experience they can't refund the money to you if the hotel itself doesn't authorize it. I booked a hotel through booking.com, when we got there it was dirty and bed bug infested, so we moved rooms, this room had the same problem except the light in the bathroom also didn't work. We didn't stay, spent maybe 2 hours on the phone with booking.com, they told me that the hotel wouldn't refund my money so there was nothing they could do. Had to eat the cost of the hotel we didn't stay at, and the one that we did stay at.

Comment: Just don't do it. "Problem" solved.

Comment: When you make a statement, end it with a period.  This is a statement: "Now, the host has e-mailed me offering me a discount on the payment if I cancel the booking."  Putting a question mark at the end instead of a period makes it look like you are asking us if you received that message.  How would we know?  Statements end with a period. Period.

Comment: Excellent question. Same thing happened to me recently with a four-star hotel in Germany that I booked for a business trip.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Part of the host's contract with booking.com is that booking.com will take a [commission fee of 10-25%](https://partner.booking.com/en-us/help/commission-invoices-tax/how-much-commission-do-i-pay) out of each booking made through them.

So if you cancel your booking.com reservation and pay the host directly, the host will get the full amount of your payment, instead of just 75-90% of it, and booking.com gets cut out of the deal.  The discount they're offering is a sort of kickback so that you get a piece of the savings also.

However, this sort of thing is undoubtedly forbidden by the host's contract with booking.com, so basically they are asking you to help them defraud booking.com.  If booking.com finds out about this, they'll probably cancel the host's account, and maybe sue them if they've been doing it a lot.    I don't know whether you yourself would be at any legal risk as well, but it certainly doesn't seem like a very good idea to me.

Comment: If the host is willing to break their contract with booking.com, there is no reason to trust them to keep a deal with the OP.

Comment: Cancelling your booking would also mean cancelling any guarantees booking.com may offer. If it turns out to be a scam, the place is unacceptable, or something else goes wrong, booking.com has no responsibility anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. What do you suggest I do? Do I still go through with this booking? I’ve already made a prepayment. I’m just worried that something will go wrong when I arrive.

Comment: @theman I would simply use your current booking through Booking.com, unless the savings to your are significant enough that you're happy to deal with any problems (such as potentially losing the reservation) should something go wrong.

Comment: They may also want to give your room for someone that isn't booked via booking.com so they get an extra 10-25%, while you end up with **no room**.

Comment: Being a developer in hotel industry, I know it is not very uncommon for the hotel to overbook. So their offer for a better room at a lessor rate is aimed to accommodate more customers and still make a profit. The catch here is `better room`. If it is the same room, you can assume it is something shady related to the commission.

Comment: @ZachLipton Does booking.com offer any guarantees besides the ability to write a bad review about a place you didn't like?

Comment: Reading of booking.com T&C shows that they have a Price Match. By using the Price Match, booking.com would possibly happily Price Match the discount, whilst thanking your for reporting the host.

Comment: @theman I would suggest, if possible, cancel the booking, and select another different place. if it's scamming booking.com and/or some other shady deal, it'd be better if you avoid this place completely. (I'm not paranoid AF) also read some reviews about that place and area by people who really've been there would be helpful on getting an idea about the situation

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev [In my experience, no.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142476/host-telling-me-to-cancel-my-booking-in-exchange-for-a-discount#comment353905_142476)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I had an experience where the hotel wouldn't take my passport as a valid form of id; they claimed that the id needed an address on it, but no where on their notes on their booking profile had they specified such a restriction. I found another hotel nearby and stayed there and reported the incident to Booking, and Booking reimbursed me the cancellation fee for the hotel that wouldn't honor my reservation *and* had me send them a copy of the receipt for the hotel where I ended up staying and with it reimbursed me for the full cost of the stay.

Comment: @DavyM Apparently the difference between your case and Grumpy's is that you didn't refuse to stay in unacceptable conditions, instead, the hotel found you non-admissible. I'll hazard a guess that booking.com is more strict with such hotels to discourage overbooking and then ditching the extra guests for made up reasons.

Comment: @Aron Price Match does not work "If the other offer is on a website that doesn’t reveal the property or accommodation type you’ll be staying in until after booking." which *could* be construed as being sort of the case here, more specifically the discount was only offered after the booking.

Comment: @nic "If the other offer is on a website that..." I am pretty sure that part is false, so, no, it would not apply.

Answer (score 34):

TL;DR Keep your original booking.

It's possible that the host found out that the demand on accommodation for the period of your booking went up, so they will have no trouble renting the place for more money to someone else if you cancel. Or maybe they are already overbooked and are looking for the least expensive way out.

The thing you have to understand is that between the moment you cancel and the moment you rebook (with the same host or otherwise), **you have no room**. If you have free cancellation, at least don't cancel until you have a new confirmed booking on better terms.

Also keep in mind that booking.com provides added value to you compared to a reservation on the side. E.g. the host will be inclined to give better rooms to booking.com customers who can otherwise trash them in reviews.

If you go to a certain place regularly, it's a good idea to forego booking.com and get a reservation directly with the host *you know and trust*. This doesn't seem to be your case though.

Answer (score 6):

The person who has contacted you as "the host" may not be who they say they are. They could be a junior employee who is able to slip you the key to an unbooked room, while pocketing your reservation fee. They could even be a scammer totally unconnected to the accommodation who has found out you are staying there (maybe from your social media posts, or maybe they have hacked into the accommodation's booking.com account). They would take your money, but when you arrived at the accommodation you would have no booking.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have pointed out that the host probably wants to defraud booking.com.  They're probably honest to you, but you may not want to count on probably.

One similar situation that is probably not fraud: suppose you're staying there already and want to renew your stay.  You could do so through booking.com, or directly with the landlord.  By then you'd already know them in person, and know the place, so it would be safer for you to do so.